Modelica derivative in function annotation syntax
I want to get the derivative of a function in Modelica, but im not sure what im missing in my example code. I saw some examples, but im unsure whats the reason the "function derivative" -way fails; since its the same code as the "Model derivative"?
My understanding is that for using derivatives in functions, you need to add a new function, that is doing the derivative calculation.
The code example which is commented out ("Model derivative") works, but I want to do the same using functions...
Here is an easy to understand example to show what i want to do:
    package ModelicaSyntaxTests
  model FunctionDerivativeTest
  
  extends Modelica.Units.SI;
  
type height = Real;
type velocity = Real //(unit= Modelica.Units.SI.Velocity);
type acceleration = Real //(unit= Modelica.Units.SI.Acceleration);
type time = Real //(unit= Modelica.Units.SI.Time);
  

parameter height h(start=1000,fixed = false);
  //parameter height h0 = 1000;
velocity v(start=0, fixed = false);
parameter acceleration a = -9.81;
  
  
  /*
  initial equation
  h = h0;
  
  equation  
    
  v = der(h);
  der(v) = a;
  */
  
  equation
  h= Function(v=v,t=time);
  v= DerFunction(a=a,t=time);
  
 
  annotation(experiment(StartTime = 0 ,StopTime = 20));
  end FunctionDerivativeTest;
  
  
  function Function
   input Real  v;
   input Real  t;
   output Real h;
    
    protected
    
    algorithm
  
  h:=v*t ;
annotation(derivative=DerFunction);
    end Function;

    function DerFunction
    
    //input Real h;
    input Real a;
    input Real  t;
    output Real v;

    algorithm
    
v:=a*t ;

    end DerFunction;

end ModelicaSyntaxTests;


I strongly recommend to NOT use Modelica Keywords as class/variable name!
https://specification.modelica.org/master/lexical-structure.html#modelica-keywords
It works here, because Modelica is case sensitive

As for your question there are a large number of misunderstandings:

Your "derivative" function is not a derivative of the original function; a function with two inputs has a derivative with four inputs (the original inputs and their derivatives; note that there are exceptions for high order derivatives), your derivative has two input (or three included the out-commented one) - not four
Prefer smoothOrder over derivative-annotation.
Derivative functions are rarely called directly; it is normally implicitly called
If you want to have two functions called Function and DerFunction, and call them just do that - don't use the derivative-annotation.

Using smoothOrder mean writing:
function Function
   input Real  t;
   output Real h;

 protected

 algorithm
   h:=1000-9.82*t^2/2 ;
   annotation(smoothOrder=10);
 end Function;

The smoothOrder will here work as if we had derivative=DerFunction  where:
function DerFunction
   input Real  t;
   input Real dt;
   output Real dh;

 protected

 algorithm
   dh:=-9.82*t*dt;
   annotation(smoothOrder=9);
 end DerFunction;

(Except that you write less, thus reducing the risk of errors.)
As for being implicitly called it means:
  Real h,v,a;
equation
  h= Function(time);
  v = der(h); // This will implicitly call DerFunction
  a = der(v); // This will implicitly differentiate DerFunction  

This should generate a correct derivative-function. Note that I here used the trajectory-solution as Function - in general that does not make sense, but if something is only a function of time it must be the trajectory of the variable.
There are also other simple errors in the model:

Don't define a type called time; and in general try to use initial upper case for types.
Don't extends Modelica.Units.SI
The formatting is all over the place
The // comments goes until the end of the line; using // ... ; to comment out parts of a line does thus not work as the semi-colon is  also commented out.


So when I want the derivative of a value, I usually should do that in the "model", right? I dont exactly understand what smoothOrder is used for then, since this model isnt dependent on it.

Yes, if you want the derivative of a variable (or expression) just use der.
